# Save original variable/command for invocation later

Tags: macros

I have a rather document in which I have globally set `\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}`. However, in one specific location I would like to use the original `\epsilon`. I tried `\newcommand{\originalepsilon}{\epsilon}` before replacing its definition with `\renewcommand` in the preamble, but I guess it does not work this way. What is the best way to implement this? It is a long document where I would still like the `\epsilon` command to invoke `\varepsilon` everywhere else except in this one instance.

Comment: You have to use `\let\originalepsilon\epsilon` before redefining `\epsilon`.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks egreg, indeed it was `\let` as was shown by example in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845887/how-do-i-use-renewcommand-to-get-back-my-greek-letters which I did not find before.